# Take a screenshot when get incoming call

Tags: ios, swift

I want to take a screenshot when someone call me. The problem is when i get to incoming call and try to screenshot, app takes own screen. How can i get incoming screen?(Sorry for my poor english)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var callCenter = CTCallCenter()
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        callCenter.callEventHandler = { (call:CTCall!) in

            switch call.callState {
            case CTCallStateConnected:
                print("CTCallStateConnected")
                self.callConnected()
            case CTCallStateDisconnected:
                print("CTCallStateDisconnected")
                self.callDisconnected()
            case CTCallStateIncoming:
                print("CTCallStateIncoming")
                self.callIncoming()
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }

    func callIncoming(){
        captureScreen()
    }

    func callConnected(){
        captureScreen()
    }

    func callDisconnected() {
        captureScreen()
    }

    func captureScreen() {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
        view.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image!, nil, nil, nil)
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        imageView.image = image
    }
}
```

Comment: there is a lot of privacy violation in your idea, which is not supported by Apple.

Answer (score 4):

Agree with @holex - you cannot. iOS deliberately restricts apps accessing each other's data for security/privacy reasons. Even if there were a workaround for this, your app would likely get rejected when submitted.